# Sending object over socket java?

Tags: java, android, sockets, object

I am trying to send object and recieve object over socket but getting some error.

Earlier i am trying this way which is working fine but i am not able to send heavy size object.Below is code
**On Sending**

```
            ObjectOutputStream mOut=null;
            mSocket = new Socket();
            mSocket.bind(null);
            mSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(mPeerIP, Constants.WELCOME_SOCKET_PORT)), 3000);
            mOut =  new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
            mOut.writeObject(mMsg);
            mOut.flush();
```

**On Recieving**

```
mIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream()));
            Object receivedMsg = mIn.readObject();
```

After searching on stackoverflow i came to know to send object in the form of bytes so that large files can also be tranfered: below is code.

**On Sending side**

```
ObjectOutput mOut=null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out=null;
mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.bind(null);
mSocket.connect...
out = mSocket.getOutputStream();
mOut =  new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
mOut.writeObject(mMsg);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
out.write(bytes);
```

**On Recieving side**

```
InputStream in = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
in=mSocket.getInputStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
for(int s; (s=in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) **//At this line i am getting Error**
{
    baos1.write(buffer, 0, s);
}
byte result[] = baos1.toByteArray();
bis=new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
mIn = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
Object o = mIn.readObject();
```

But using this i am continuously getting this error

```
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:588)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-6930/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-7057/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-21 01:15:40.267 5391-7057/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:588)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:588)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at com.nearpeer.app.NewConnectionWorkerThread.SendDiscoveryMessage(NewConnectionWorkerThread.java:426)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at com.nearpeer.app.NewConnectionWorkerThread.ActiveDiscoveryProcedure(NewConnectionWorkerThread.java:386)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at com.nearpeer.app.NewConnectionWorkerThread.InitiateRelevantActiveTransaction(NewConnectionWorkerThread.java:682)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at com.nearpeer.app.NewConnectionWorkerThread.run(NewConnectionWorkerThread.java:78)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
08-21 01:15:40.277 5391-7005/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
```

You can also suggest me to better way to do this if you have an idea.

Comment: please paste the error as a code block instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Edit the question you can check

Comment: Seems like a firewall issue, are the sender / receiver programs located on the **same computer**? or two different computers on the **same LAN**? If not then you will have to look into port forwarding on the server side.

Comment: Its an android application i am communicating with other android application.Its work fine while doing above method but getting error by doing 2nd thing.

Comment: Where did you read that rubbish? All that extra code in the second version doesn't solve anything. It just adds latency and wastes space. Use the first version. If you have a problem with that, post it.

Comment: @EJP Hey i told 1st version is not working for big files.